# Fortify scan on .net core project

Tags: .net-core, fortify

I have a `.NET Core` project I am trying to run a *Fortify* scan on.  As far as I know there is no *VS2017* *Fortify* plugin available just yet, but I am curious if at all possible I can use the `.NET Core SDK` to work around the plugin to still perform a Fortify scan?  If so how would I be able to incorporate that in to my *clean*, *translate* and *scan* commands?

Current Fortify version:

```
HPE Security Fortify Static Code Analyzer 16.10.0095 (using JVM 1.8.0_72)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core is supported in Fortify SCA v17.20